# XCode 4 console won't take user input

Tags: c++, xcode4, user-input

In XCode 4, when I run something like this:

```
string input;
cout << "Enter command" << endl;
getline(cin, input);
cout << "You entered: " << input << endl;
```

I see my "Enter command" prompt in the console. But when I place my mouse cursor below it and start typing the cursor doesn't move, and my keystrokes don't show up. It basically behaves like a read-only text box. What am I doing wrong? How can I interact with my program as if it were running in the terminal?

Comment: Does the console have focus...?

Comment: It must, right? I am getting a blinking cursor in it when I click.

Comment: This has happened to me occasionally. Have you tried restarting Xcode?

Comment: Yes. This has been a persistant problem. I have never been able to enter anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you pressing **Return** or **Enter** at the end of your input line?
For some keyboard the enter and return are on the same button, but if you press "shift" key, while pushing the enter/return button scanf will work.

- Unshifted must be the Return
- Shifted must be the Enter.

Comment: In XCode 5.x, I need to push shift+enter key to generate the Enter key code. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Shifted must be the Enter

Answer (score 1):

From the site “[Xcode Tools Tips](http://www.meandmark.com/xcodetips.html)”:

> When debugging a command line program
>   with Xcode, one problem you may have
>   is figuring out where to input data
>   and read the program's output. If you
>   open the debugging console window by
>   clicking the Console button, you will
>   be able to see your program's output,
>   but you will get an error message any
>   time you try to enter input in the
>   console window. Where do you enter the
>   input your program needs?
>
> The answer is Xcode's standard I/O
>   log. The standard I/O log works
>   similarly to Xcode's run log when you
>   run your program in Xcode without the
>   debugger. Choose Debug > Standard I/O
>   Log to open the log window. Now when
>   you debug your program, you will see
>   its output in the standard I/O log,
>   and you will be able to input any data
>   your program needs to run.

By the way, all I did to find that quote was to highlight your question in the browser, and select “Search” in the browser’s right click menu. It was the fourth hit in Google’s list.

I think, it’s pretty much very often a good idea to google before asking!

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Hi, thank you. I think this is specific to older versions of XCode. I can find no such option in XCode 4, and I found a post that said the console window is supposed to handle input. I did spend a long time on google before posting my question, but I wasn't able to find anything useful.

Comment: This option has been removed in XCode 4 :-(

Comment: after i "highlight this question in the browser, and select “Search” in the browser’s right click menu" i come to this question on Google

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom pane of the debug window[which shows variables and their values], there is a search toolbar and a 3 option box in the upper right hand corner.  Click on the middle of the three options which will display the main debug output to the right of the variable pane.  The top pane is only for output.  The right pane can be used to enter input.

I hope this helps.  Sorry that the note is late.

Comment: This is specific to XCode 4.0+