# C Programming in Xcode, scanf doesn't read int

Tags: c, scanf

I'm practicing C programming language before jump to objective-c, so I'm using the last version of XCode 4.6.3 (I believe this is the last version).
I want to read an input, a  numeric input (age), and show the dog age of a person.
Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int age;
    printf("How old are you? \n");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    age = age *7;
    printf(\nIn dog years you are %d years old",age);
    return 0;
}
```

so i enter my age and it doesn't show the result, sry for the newb question but I've already asked 4 people from work and nothing :(
Thanks!

[image: debugging]

The Answer!
I don't know why this happens, but I solved it (kind of fun hahahaha). I'm using apple keyboard and the NumLock ENter key doesn't work for debugg o.O . When I use the main Enter key, it works! Thanks everyone =)

Comment: Hi. "I'm practicing C programming language before jump to objective-c" - that's cool! It is the right order in which to learn those languages. Please consider getting used to some [coding and formatting standards](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) so that your code is easier to read. Also note that this question is not related to the IDE being used, rather to the language and the usage of a library function.

Comment: @KevinDTimm it shows nothing, I used some break points and debug, the error is on "scanf". It seems to don't get the input. I type the input,25, and hit enter, then the program exits.

Comment: @H2CO3 Hello, thnx for helping, I'll read the formatting standards!

Comment: see the answer from @dasblinkenblight, also - when you single step the code (since you're in the debugger) does it never return from `scanf`?

Comment: @KevinDTimm no, it never return from scanf =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This often happens because the program exits before the output buffer gets a chance to empty itself onto the console. Adding `\n` to the end of `printf`'s format line should fix this problem:

```
printf("\nIn dog years you are %d years old\n",age);
```

Printing `\n` to an output stream which is connected to console "flushes" the output unless you change this setting in your program.

Note: C provides a shorter way of multiplying by 7: instead of

```
age = age * 7;
```

you can write

```
age *= 7;
```

Comment: You bring up a good point about the output stream, but that isn't his issue here.  I guess you can your answer is too good for his problem...?

Comment: @MohammadS. I don't think the missing quote is more than a typo the OP introduced while typing up the question, because the program wouldn't have compiled without it.

Comment: If he's new to programming, he may not know about compiling then running.  Or he may not know that hes getting compile time errors.  We'll only really know when he gives us more info.

Comment: @MohammadS. - unlikely, since he's running in the debugger

Comment: Hello, sry for delay, I'm using the quotes! I misstyped! the \n at end didn't resolve the problem, thats why I think the issue is with XCode =S

Comment: @JoséFlávio How do you compile and start the program? Does it print the "How old are you?" question? Does it let you type your answer? What happens next?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, it print the "How old are you?" and I can type the input. When i hit enter it seems to exit (return 0) because it stop debugging

Comment: @JoséFlávio You can set a breakpoint on the `return 0` line, or add another `scanf("%d",&age);` after the `printf` to prevent it from exiting the debugger.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've edit the question with a picture, could you take a look? I hit 25 and then ENTER when first stops at Break point, then only hit ENTER some times, step into, type 25 and hit enter again. Then it leave debugging without printing the last printf =/

Comment: @JoséFlávio It looks like you're having [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6482216/335858): your input does not actually gets read. The link discusses the fix.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't know why this happens, but I solved it (kind of fun hahahaha). I'm using apple keyboard and the NumLock ENter key doesn't work for debugg o.O . When I use the main Enter key, it works! Thanks everyone =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a **quote** here:

```
printf(\nIn dog years you are %d years old",age);
```

Change it to:

```
printf("\nIn dog years you are %d years old",age);
```

I don't know how this is even **compiling** for you.  You are probably getting **compile time errors**.  Remember to **compile** your code first, then **run**.  When it runs, remember to enter your input in the console, then hit the ENTER key.

I just tried this and it works for me:  http://ideone.com/NFU2Ry

Comment: sry, I miss typed. I'm using the quote! Thanks