# Xcode won't take user input from console

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to run C++ code that takes user input through the Xcode console, but Xcode refuses to cooperate. Output appears in the console, and clicking on the console makes a cursor appear and blink, but typing does nothing. Input was working previously which makes the problem more confusing.

I found some questions about this issue ([XCode 4 console won't take user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481943/xcode-4-console-wont-take-user-input)) but the answers are incomplete or irrelevant.

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1, and restarting both Xcode and my computer haven't fixed it.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete example.

Comment: I added an image showing what's going on. Prompt shows up, but can't input anything.

Comment: from a similar question over at apple: " first workaround is to run your command-line app from the Terminal. In the Xcode project navigator select your executable from the Products folder. Right-click and choose Show in Finder. Double-click the executable in the Finder to launch it in the Terminal."

Comment: for xcode 4-5: https://sites.google.com/site/chrislent/home/-workaround-xcode-4-5-output-window-input-echo-problem

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thanks